# Angular Observable error when adding Angular Material

Tags: javascript, angular, error-handling

I have a problem with Angular Material probably. When I am trying to import

`import { MatButtonModule, MatCardModule, MatInputModule, MatListModule, MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material';`

Of course I'm declare it in the import in my `app.module.ts` file.
I am getting below error

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/table.es5.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject'
```

Something like that I am also using Observable in my service, but when I delete the import line of Material everything is working. Can anybody assist in how to solve this problem?

Comment: what rxjs Angular and @angular/material version you're using?

Comment: "rxjs": "^5.5.10" and "@angular/material": "5.2.4",

Comment: can you check if the version in the package.json files of both rxjs and material in your node_modules folder match the versions that you mentioned?

Comment: try adding `import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';`

Comment: That is only one of a lot of errors. I found that in node I've rxjs 7.. So probably that is the problem I will try to install material in v7.

Comment: I updated angular material, but still have the same problem.